# Google Places API in iOS application

Tags: ios, google-places

Let me share my findings before asking the question.

Google Places API documentation says:
"Note: To use the Google Places API you must first request a Maps API
client ID and cryptographic key which you must use to sign your
request URLs. For information on signing URL requests, please see the
URL Authentication documentation within the Web Service APIs home
page."

1. The Google Places API is still in developer preview.
   http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/
2. We need a Client ID (required) and a Signature (required) to use
   the Google Places API.
   http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/webservices/index.html#URLSigning
3. And, to get the Signature, we need a Google Adsense account to get
   Adsense publisher id (required).
   http://gmaps-ws-console.appspot.com/
4. You can find the requirements to use the Google Places API here.
   http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/index.html#Requirements
5. The Signup page for Google Maps API suggest that, "Your service
   must be freely accessible to end users. To use Google mapping
   technology in other types of applications, please use Google Maps API
   Premier. See this FAQ for more information."
   http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/maps/signup.html

Now, here's what i want to know.

I'm planning on using Google Places API in my iOS application. I don't
want to use Adsense. Can i still access the Google Places API for
free? How?

If i can't access the Google Places API for free, what are the costs
associated with using this service, and the available payment models?
I wasn't able to find any particular resources for this information.

Here's a specific scenario. What if my iOS application is free. The
free version uses Google Places API. But... my iOS application has
some additional features which are exposed using In-app Purchase (paid
features). The paid features do not use Google Places API. Is this
acceptable?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We opened up the Google Places API to all developers this week at Google I/O and simplified the Terms and authentication:

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/05/places-everybody-show-is-about-to-begin.html

You no longer need to sign your requests, but instead just use a key obtained using the Google APIs console. An AdSense ID is no longer required, but you will need to go though a credit card based identity check in order to upgrade from 1,000 to 100,000 request per day.

You can use the Places API in mobile apps that are free or sold online through a mobile app store such as the Apple App Store or Android Market. For fee desktop apps however will require a Maps API Premier license which will be offered once the Places API graduates from Google Code Labs.

For information on getting started, see the docs:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/

HTH,

Thor

Comment: What about paid desktop applications being sold through an app store?

Comment: @Thor Mitchell   Is it possible to use the client id and signature to access the Google Place API. I found that the client id and the signature could be used in the Google GEO API. But I fail to use the client id to access Google Place API.