# Google Maps SDK not showing all places

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

I am using *Google Maps SDK* to show map in my app. Everything is working fine except the fact that my mapview looks empty, cause there are not all places are shown. When I open same location from google map app all places likes Shops, Offices, Hospitals etc. are displayed. What is problem with my mapview.

I'm using this code as written on *Google Developers* site:

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:72.34 longitude:19.45 zoom:18];
gmapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:mainView.bounds camera:camera];
gmapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
```

Here are screenshots of my app & google maps app:

**My App:**

[image]

**Google Maps:**

[image]

These are screenshots of same place!

Comment: Looks like a bug or a licensing issue to me...

Comment: @JasonWray thanks for taking the time to try to improve multiple posts. However, as edits made by users below 2,000 rep each need to be peer reviewed StackOverflow asks that you make an attempt to correct as many issues with a post that you can find so as to best use the volunteers' time. Your other edits were rejected for not attempting to do more to improve the posts. Once you reach 2,000 rep you can make more minor edits freely.

Answer (score 1):

Google Map for iOS vs Google Places for iOS are 2 different APIs. I think the one that you are using is Only Google Map API, so, all the places are empty. If you want to put places on the map, I think you will need to learn how to use Google Places API.

For more information, you could learn from these few helpful websites:

1. [Google Places API in iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535361/google-places-api-in-ios-application)
2. https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/
3. http://www.raywenderlich.com/13160/using-the-google-places-api-with-mapkit

Comment: I am showing map to user as per destinations location, your can move through map. How to display places no matter where user moves?

Comment: You need to use the Nearby Search Requests API and it will return a list of places based on the user current location. Then, you will need to put the places on the map using markers (may be with nice icon). See: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search

Comment: I tried above methods but still not getting all the places. The places shown in Google maps app are still much more than mine.

Comment: This one you will have to ask Google as I am not sure how much data Google is willing to share to you based on your current location and the technology behind it. I believe you will not get 100% as Google definitely will reserve part of its data or technology to itself. There is a chance that the Google Map app has Places data hardcoded inside the app which does not need a server call every second. While the data that you get from the Google Places API is limited because it is getting from the Google Places server.