# IOS - How to provide suggestions when inputting locations

Tags: ios, xcode, location

How do you implement suggestions when a user starts typing in their city/location into an iOS app text field? For example, if you look at the yelp or maps app, when you start typing in a city it will provide suggestions based on what you start typing. Is there a way to do this, like somehow get a list of all the CLRegions in the CoreLocation framework, or some other way of implementing this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution for this is to use someone else's (web-based) geocoding database - geocoding is a complex problem that you don't want to solve yourself :-).  Geocoding is the act of taking a textual address and turning it into a latitude/longitude.  Typeahead for geocoding is a helpful feature that requires fairly large databases that likely aren't suitable for mobile apps, thus my recommendation to use one of the web-based geocoding services for this.

Google's places API is probably a good candidate:

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete?csw=1

Check out this answer for some commentary from Google from 2011 when they first opened up that API in 2011:
[Google Places API in iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535361/google-places-api-in-ios-application)